# How to query router to find Dhcp Lease Info?

Tags: android

I want to get list of IP and MAC addresses of all devices assigned by router, for that I want to query router to find 'Dhcp Info'  using Java in Android.

Comment: I think you have to query the router using HTTP protocol using ID and password. And open the page where the DHCP lease info is shown and parse the page for the lease time.

Comment: @johntheripp3r thanks for your response. Could you suggest a way to query the router without using user interface (running in the background).

Comment: To do that use [Default HTTP Client](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html) and [AyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score -1):

different routers provide different API. You'd better send something like a ping query to all IP adresses according to address assigned to you. Like if your IP is 192.168.0.18 then ping all IPs 192.168.0.1-192.168.0.255.

Answer (score -1):

@VikramGiri To get lease duration in Android, try:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.getDhcpInfo().leaseDuration;
```

This works if your router utilises **DHCP**. For utilised **static** IP address, the above code will always return zero instead of a number in milliseconds representing the lease duration.

The `DhcpInfo` class also provide other fields you might be interested in like: DNS addresses, IP addresses, gateway, netmask, etc. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/DhcpInfo.html#leaseDuration) for more info.

Since you're new here, don't forget to tick answers if they are correct so others who read your post in the future will know that a given answer(s) is/are correct...

Answer (score -1):

I guess this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fillevoss.router.config&hl=en) is doing the same thing. Looks like he (the developer of the app) is also parsing the webpage to get the information. 
In the images on the play store of the above app you can see he is displaying the whole router webpage and parsing the same page to get the information. 
Check out the screenshot#2 of the [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fillevoss.router.config&hl=en) .